# Finding absolute extrema in a region

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

Given $-8x^3-6y^2+12xy=0$, find its absolute maximum and minimum in the region $x≥0$ and $y≥-1$.

So far, I got the critical points $(0,0)$ and $(1/2,1/2)$, and that $(1/2,1/2)$ yields the absolute maximum value. I don't know if I solved it correctly since its in an unbounded region (Or is it? I'm not sure, I only learned the ones with bounded regions). I feel like I may be overthinking this? Anyways, any help/hint would be appreciated!

Comment: There is no global minimum... if you set $y =-1$ the values of $f$ are given by $-8x^3-12x-6$, which tends to $-\infty$ as $x \to +\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considered the regularity of the objective function, any local or global extrema will occur either in stationary points in the interior of the region, or at points in the boundary.

Setting $y=-1$, you see that there is no hope of having a global minimum.

At the boundary, we have $f = -6y^2, y\ge -1$ or $f = -8 x^3 -12 x -6, x \ge 0.$

At the only local maximum in the interior, we have $f = \frac 12$.

Putting all this together, there is no global minimum and either the global maximum is $\frac 12$, or there is no global maximum. Can you proceed?

Comment: Yes, I think I can now. Thank you so much!